# Telerik: RadGridView Rowcount

Tags: c#, xaml, telerik

I have a Grid that I am trying to set up using Telerik.  What I am trying to do is add a footer to the grid that counts the number of rows that are displayed.

My XAML code snippet looks like this:

```
 <telerik:RadGridView Grid.Row="1"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RouteGroups}"
        SelectionMode="Multiple"
        ShowGroupPanel="False"
        ShowColumnFooters="true"
        atchbhv:RadGridViewMultipleSelection.SelectedItemsSource="{Binding SelectedRouteGroups}"
        IsEnabled="{Binding SelectAllRouteGroups, Converter={StaticResourceInverseBooleanConv}}">
        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
               <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="RouteGroup"
                         DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Item1.RouteGroup.RouteGroupDesc}"/>
        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
 </telerik:RadGridView>
```

What I want to do is count the "RouteGroup" and I am guessing I will need the C# RowsCount function?

```
public int RowsCount { get; }
```

Am I going about this the correct way?  I am a little bit lost as to how I am going to send the rowCount back to the xaml file to populate the footer.

Any help is appreciated; Thanks.

Comment: Check out this link on the Telerik forums. I think this is exactly what you are looking for: http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-show-the-total-number-of-record-in-footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, I figured out the issue; I was just missing a few lines in my xaml code

```
<telerik:RadGridView Grid.Row="1"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Locations}"
        SelectionMode="Multiple"
        ShowGroupPanel="False"
        ShowColumnFooters="true"
        atchbhv:RadGridViewMultipleSelection.SelectedItemsSource="{Binding SelectedLocations}"
        IsEnabled="{Binding SelectAllLocations, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConv}}">
                <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                       <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="LocHandle"DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Item1.LocHandle}">
                               <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.AggregateFunctions>
                                       <telerik:CountFunction Caption="Count: " />
                               </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.AggregateFunctions>
                       </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
                      <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="LocDesc"DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Item1.LocDesc}"/>
                </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```